# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'

Tags: python, python-packaging

This is my first time build my own python package.

My dirs layout is shown as following:

```
my_pkg
   |- setup.py
   |- __init__.py
   |- main_func.py
   |- utils
         |- __init__.py
         |- mod1.py
         |- mod2.py
```

and inside `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name='my_pkg',
        version='0.0.1.dev1',
        description='blablabla',
        author='JimChen',
        author_email='jim71183@gmail.com',
        url='https://www.google.com.tw/',
        packages=find_packages(exclude=['imgs','__pycache__'])
)
```

After execute `python setup.py install`, I can see `my_pkg` shown in `pip list`, but when I tried to import it with `import my_pkg`, there comes an error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to import the file with file's name

Comment: Damn, it really worked.How should I change my file directory that make users import my_pkg like `from my_pkg import main_func`

Answer (score 0):

Answer on my own :

pkg directory :

```
my_pkg
   |- setup.py
   |- my_pkg
      |- __init__.py
      |- main_func.py
      |- utils
            |- __init__.py
            |- mod1.py
            |- mod2.py
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name='my_pkg',
        version='0.0.1.dev1',
        description='blablabla',
        author='JimChen',
        author_email='jim71183@gmail.com',
        url='https://www.google.com.tw/',
        packages=['my_pkg']
)
```